# The response for the ajax request i make is empty, it works fine when i type the url manually while working in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

The response for the ajax request i make is empty, it works fine when i type the url manually. And can anyone help me to pass the url variable in my javascript to blade at `{{URL::to()}}` here is my code.....
here is the controller,

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Package;

class CreatePackageController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $package=Package::all();
        return view('transactions.create_package',compact('package'));
    }

public function getId($pack_no){
    $pack=Package::get()->where('Packagecode',$pack_no);
    $id=$pack->pluck('id')[0];
    $this->get($id);
}

public function get($id){
    $package = Package::findOrFail($id);
    $items = $package->items;
    return response()->json($package);
}}
```

here is my route

```
Route::get('/get_package_id/{pack_no}','CreatePackageController@getId');
```

here is my ajax

```
 $('#package_code').on('change',function(){
    var url="get_package_id/" +this.value;
    console.log(url);
    $.get("{{URL::to('get_package_id/')}}",function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    );
 });
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `getId()` function.

Comment: @patricus but the `get()` function is returning the response

Comment: `get()` is returning a value to `getId()`, but then `getId()` is not doing anything with that value. You need to also return that value from `getId()`.

Comment: @patricus i tried inserting all the code inside the `get()` function into the `getId()` function and it kinda worked. thanks dude

Comment: @patricus can you help me in figuring out how to pass a javascript variable to blade , that is the `url`  variable to `{{URL::to()}}` part in the javascript code

Comment: You just needed to change your last line to `return $this->get($id);`. You can't pass a javascript variable to blade. Javascript is client side, blade is server side. You could build javascript using blade, but you can't go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error in the javascript:

```
$('#package_code').on('change',function(){
  var url="get_package_id/" +this.value;
  console.log(url);
  $.get(url,function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put javascript variables inside a php function like URL::to().

You should use your defined `var url` inside your `$.get` call instead.